# Invalidate block cache programmatically

Tags: 8, caching

I have a block that is cached per page. However, I need a way to invalidate it's cache in code per page or node. (Or, if no way, all cache per block id).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `SystemMenuBlock` of core is invalidated when its menu changes because this method:

```
public function getCacheTags() {
  // Even when the menu block renders to the empty string for a user, we want
  // the cache tag for this menu to be set: whenever the menu is changed, this
  // menu block must also be re-rendered for that user, because maybe a menu
  // link that is accessible for that user has been added.
  $cache_tags = parent::getCacheTags();
  $cache_tags[] = 'config:system.menu.' . $this->getDerivativeId();
  return $cache_tags;
}
```

I think you can solve your problem in the same way.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @AlexeiRayu did you get this working? I have a similar issue with a block that extends SystemMenuBlock. All the node tags are added correctly but I can't seem to get it to invalidate on a node save.

Comment: @masterchief I got this working, yes. I ended up checking the way that Drupal 8 caching works - it actually has tags that cover all those requests. I don't remember what precisely I did - but I remember it was some tag, something standard.

Comment: @AlexeiRayu nice! I had mine solved in a slightly different way. The problem was with our template, we were prepocessing the menu and creating a new key that wasn't set as the render element in the theme hook. This meant that the render element that contained the cache tags were being ignored!